# laplace transform of the given equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how will I prove that 
$$
\frac{s+a}{s^2+b^2}
$$
is the Laplace transform of the following equation 
$$
\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(bt+\theta)
$$
where $\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$?

Comment: Maybe try using the double angle formula for sine function?

Comment: I tried that, but I have an extra $b$ on the numerator. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the Laplace transform by $\mathcal{L}$. Using the double-angle formula
$$\sin(A+B) = \sin(A)\cos(B) + \cos(A)\sin(B),$$
we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}(\sin(bt+\theta)) & = \cos(\theta)\mathcal{L}(\sin(bt)) + \sin(\theta)\mathcal{L}(\cos(bt)) \\
& = \cos(\theta)\left(\frac{b}{s^2 + b^2}\right) + \sin(\theta)\left(\frac{s}{s^2 + b^2}\right).
\end{align*}
Since $\theta=\tan^{-1}(b/a)$, $\tan\theta = b/a$ and one can show that
$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}, \ \ \sin(\theta) = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}. $$
Using this and the linearity of Laplace transform, we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}(\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\sin(bt+\theta)) & = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\mathcal{L}(\sin(bt+\theta)) \\
& = \left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{s^2 + b^2}\right)[b\cos(\theta) + s\sin(\theta)] \\
& = \left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{s^2 + b^2}\right)\left[\frac{ba}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} + \frac{sb}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\right]\\
& = \frac{ba + sb}{s^2 + b^2} \\
& = \frac{b(s+a)}{s^2 + b^2}.
\end{align*}